# Sightly get Page object by path

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

Why the following code doesn't work in my component?

```
<sly data-sly-test.thatPage="${pageManager.getPage @path=properties.pagePath}" data-sly-unwrap>
      <div>${thatPage.getPath}</div>
</sly>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you cannot invoke methods with arguments/parameters in HTL expressions.

Your best bet in this case is to create a helper Use-Object (either a POJO or a Sling Model) that allows passing the path when it's initialised and has a getter for the page corresponding to the path.

Comment: Is there any particular design reason, for providing PageManager as implicit object and not allowing to invoke its methods with parameters ?

Comment: HTL does not allow calling methods with parameters because the original designers felt this would enforce a better separation of concern between the model/business-logic and the view/rendering template. A number of global objects are available from HTL in AEM to make it easier for developers to access commonly used properties (see https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/global-objects.html). Some of these however have APIs that require parameters for the methods, these are more suitable to be passed down to Use-Objects.